# Brother Mobile SDK Printing From Custom IOS Application

Tags: ios, networking, printing, brother-print-sdk

I created an IOS Application to print Labels from a QL-820NMBc. Everything works exactly as intended code wise. However, the only way I can get the Label to finally Print out of the printer, is to Force Close the Mobile Application.

I am in no way a network GURU, but I feel that something is blocking the data from the Ipad to the printer to finalize the print. Just a guess.

Any help would be appreciated.

Me trying to print
[Me trying to print from custom app to iPad to brother QL820 printer](https://youtu.be/udCplQjZbCk)

```
 RCT_REMAP_METHOD(printImage, deviceInfo:(NSDictionary *)device printerUri: (NSString *)imageStr printImageOptions:(NSDictionary *)options resolver:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
{
    NSLog(@"Called the printImage function");
    BRPtouchDeviceInfo *deviceInfo = [self deserializeDeviceInfo:device];

    BRLMChannel *channel = [[BRLMChannel alloc] initWithWifiIPAddress:deviceInfo.strIPAddress];

    BRLMPrinterDriverGenerateResult *driverGenerateResult = [BRLMPrinterDriverGenerator openChannel:channel];
    if (driverGenerateResult.error.code != BRLMOpenChannelErrorCodeNoError ||
        driverGenerateResult.driver == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@", @(driverGenerateResult.error.code));

        return;
    }

    BRLMPrinterDriver *printerDriver = driverGenerateResult.driver;

    BRLMPrinterModel model = [BRLMPrinterClassifier transferEnumFromString:deviceInfo.strModelName];
    BRLMQLPrintSettings *qlSettings = [[BRLMQLPrintSettings alloc] initDefaultPrintSettingsWithPrinterModel:model];

    qlSettings.autoCut = true;

    if (options[@"autoCut"]) {
        qlSettings.autoCut = [options[@"autoCut"] boolValue];
    }

    if (options[@"labelSize"]) {
        qlSettings.labelSize = [options[@"labelSize"] intValue];
    }

    NSLog(@"Auto Cut: %@, Label Size: %@", options[@"autoCut"], options[@"labelSize"]);


    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageStr];
    BRLMPrintError *printError = [printerDriver printImageWithURL:url settings:qlSettings];
    
    if (printError.code != BRLMPrintErrorCodeNoError) {
        NSLog(@"Error - Print Image: %@", printError);
        NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.react-native-brother-printers.rn" code:1 userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:printError.description forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]];
        reject(PRINT_ERROR, @"There was an error trying to print the image", error);
        resolve(Nil);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success - Print Image %@", [printerDriver getPrinterStatus].debugDescription);
       resolve(Nil);
    }
    [printerDriver closeChannel]; //Suppose to close the channel and print, but label doesn't print until i close the app completely.
```

}

Comment: [edit] your question to show the relevant code.